# Is there any workaround to invert the color of svg icons in IE?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, svg

I am passing the following URL to an imageUrl property:

```
'{!URLFOR($Asset.slds, "assets/icons/utility/expand.svg")}'
```

due to already having these svg icons. I then invert them because they come through as white when they are not used in svg tags:

```
.k-tabstrip-items .k-item .k-image {
        width: 30px;
        margin-left: 1%;
        margin-top: -10px;
        -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
        -moz-filter: invert(100%);
        -ms-filter: invert(100%);
        -o-filter: invert(100%);
    }

    .k-tabstrip-items .k-item .k-state-active .k-image {
        -webkit-filter: invert(0%);
        -moz-filter: invert(0%);
        -ms-filter: invert(0%);
        -o-filter: invert(0%);
    }
```

However, this of course does not work in IE, neither does image masking... Is there some workaround to make these icons black in IE? I am struggling to find a workable solution (if there really is one). It could be that it will just require having black colored icons... But wanted to check if there was something I could do with CSS to get this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the fill color from a svg:

Html:

```
<svg enable-background="new 0 0 56.693 56.693" height="56.693px" id="Layer_1" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 56.693 56.693" width="56.693px" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <g>
    <path d="M30.071,27.101v-0.077c-0.016,0.026-0.033,0.052-0.05,0.077H30.071z"/>
    <path id="linkedin" fill="#000" d="M49.265,4.667H7.145c-2.016,0-3.651,1.596-3.651,3.563v42.613c0,1.966,1.635,3.562,3.651,3.562h42.12   c2.019,0,3.654-1.597,3.654-3.562V8.23C52.919,6.262,51.283,4.667,49.265,4.667z M18.475,46.304h-7.465V23.845h7.465V46.304z    M14.743,20.777h-0.05c-2.504,0-4.124-1.725-4.124-3.88c0-2.203,1.67-3.88,4.223-3.88c2.554,0,4.125,1.677,4.175,3.88   C18.967,19.052,17.345,20.777,14.743,20.777z M45.394,46.304h-7.465V34.286c0-3.018-1.08-5.078-3.781-5.078   c-2.062,0-3.29,1.389-3.831,2.731c-0.197,0.479-0.245,1.149-0.245,1.821v12.543h-7.465c0,0,0.098-20.354,0-22.459h7.465v3.179   c0.992-1.53,2.766-3.709,6.729-3.709c4.911,0,8.594,3.211,8.594,10.11V46.304z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Css:

```
svg #linkedin { 
  fill: red; //or #ff0000
}
```

In the svg the path must have the id "linkedin" to change color

```
<path id="linkedin" fill="#000" d="M49.265,[...],10.11V46.304z"/>
```

Copy of a previous answer from me

Comment: just flag as a dupliate if that's what you think it is.